# my question is how to pass the ID from one activity to another

Tags: android

In the code below, I'm trying to pass the ID of the owner and the ID of the customer to the opposite activity using Put extra and getExtra intent. However, I'm having setup activity checks if the user has filled up all of his details or not so if he didn't, the user will be directed to the setup activity. So, the problem here whenever I pass the id of the user to another activity, the setup activity take this id and checks that the user has not filled up the setup page and direct him to the setup page. I need the id of the two users for chat activity so, when any one of the users click the contact button, he should be directed to the chat activity and see the username and the id of another user. the two users have different classes and different drawer activities and different login and register. this is the owner activity and the customer activity is the same but I couldn't paste due to the limited number of words

have two users activities owner and customer. owner post cars for rent and post will be posted in both activities. in post there is contact button. contact button direct owner to chat activity and he supposes to see customer username and profile image but it only shows the personal image and username. therefore i'm trying to get the user id of the owner to use it in the cutomer activity and the opposite. but , unfortunatly when i do that, the setup activity take user id which i have took and check in user name that user have not entered his details and direct him again to setup activity

I have tried to use

Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomerDrawer.class);

intent.putExtra("OwnerID", owncurrentUserId);

startActivity(intent);

and then get the intent but it gives me the issue listed above

```
package com.example.user.carapplication;


        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.RecoverySystem;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
        import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageButton;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
        import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

        import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


        public class CustomerDrawer extends AppCompatActivity
                implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

            private FirebaseAuth CustomerAuth;
            private DatabaseReference CustomerRef, PostsRef;
            private CircleImageView CusNavProfileImge;
            private TextView CusNavProfileName;
            String currentUserId;
            private NavigationView navigationView;
            private RecyclerView postList;
            private Toolbar mToolbar;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_drawer);
                mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_app_customer);
                setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                CustomerAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                CustomerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers");
                currentUserId = CustomerAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");


                //for the navigation drawer button to open and close
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.Customer_drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();
                navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.customer_nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
                postList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.CustomerPostCars);
                postList.setHasFixedSize(true);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                postList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


                View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_customer_drawer);
                CusNavProfileName = (TextView) navView.findViewById(R.id.NavCustomerUserName);
                CusNavProfileImge = (CircleImageView) navView.findViewById(R.id.NavCustomerProfileImage);

                CustomerRef.child(currentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname")) {
                                String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                                CusNavProfileName.setText(fullname);
                            }
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                                String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                                Picasso.with(CustomerDrawer.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(CusNavProfileImge);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerDrawer.this, "Profile name does not exist...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                DisplayAllCarsPost();


            }
            public void DisplayAllCarsPost()
            {
                Query SortPostInDecentOrder = PostsRef.orderByChild("counter");

                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>
                                (
                                        Posts.class,
                                        R.layout.activity_posted__cars,
                                        PostsViewHolder.class,
                                        SortPostInDecentOrder
                                )
                        {
                            @Override
                            protected void populateViewHolder(PostsViewHolder viewHolder, Posts model, final int position)
                            {
                                final String PostKey = getRef(position).getKey();
                                viewHolder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
                                viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                                viewHolder.setCarbrand(model.getCarbrand());
                                viewHolder.setCarmodel(model.getCarmodel());
                                viewHolder.setCaryear(model.getCaryear());
                                viewHolder.setPricehour(model.getPricehour());
                                viewHolder.setPricehday(model.getPricehday());
                                viewHolder.setPriceday(model.getPriceday());
                                viewHolder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfileimage());
                                viewHolder.setPostimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPostimage());
                                viewHolder.setState( model.getState());

                                viewHolder.CancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        final DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
                                        final DatabaseReference OwnerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Owners");
                                        UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                                                    String OwnerID = intent.getStringExtra("OwnerID");
                                                    Posts posts = dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).getValue(Posts.class);
                                                    String stat = posts.getState();
                                                    String uid = posts.getUid();
                                                    if (stat.equals("Booked") && uid.equals(currentUserId)){
                                                        UserRef.child(PostKey).child("state").setValue("book");
                                                        OwnerRef.child(PostKey).child("uid").setValue(OwnerID);

                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }
                                        });


                                    }
                                });
                                viewHolder.bookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        final DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
                                        UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){


                                                    Posts posts = dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).getValue(Posts.class);
                                                    String stat = posts.getState();
                                                    if (stat.equals("book")){
                                                        UserRef.child(PostKey).child("state").setValue("Booked");
                                                        UserRef.child(PostKey).child("uid").setValue(currentUserId);

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                                viewHolder.ContactBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        final DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(PostKey);
                                        UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                                                Intent ChattBtnIntent = new Intent(CustomerDrawer.this, Chatt.class);
                                                ChattBtnIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id",PostKey);
                                                ChattBtnIntent.putExtra("userName",fullname);
                                                startActivity(ChattBtnIntent);
                                            }
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                });


                            }
                        };
                postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
            }
            public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            {
                View mView;
                Button bookButton,CancelBtn,ContactBtn;

                public PostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    mView = itemView;
                    bookButton = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.book_button);
                    CancelBtn = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
                    ContactBtn = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.contact_button);

                }

                public void setFullname(String fullname)
                {
                    TextView username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_username);
                    username.setText(fullname);
                }

                public void setProfileimage(Context ctx, String profileimage)
                {
                    CircleImageView image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.PostCircularImageView);
                    Picasso.with(ctx).load(profileimage).into(image);
                }

                public void setTime(String time)
                {
                    TextView PostTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Post_time);
                    PostTime.setText("    " + time);
                }

                public void setDate(String date)
                {
                    TextView PostDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Post_date);
                    PostDate.setText("    " + date);
                }

                public void setCarbrand(String carbrand)
                {
                    TextView PostCarbrand = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_description);
                    PostCarbrand.setText(carbrand);
                }
                public void setCarmodel(String carmodel)
                {
                    TextView PostCarmodel = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_model);
                    PostCarmodel.setText(carmodel);
                }
                public void setCaryear(String caryear)
                {
                    TextView PostCaryear = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_year);
                    PostCaryear.setText(caryear);
                }
                public void setPricehour(String pricehour)
                {
                    TextView PostPricehour = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_pricehour);
                    PostPricehour.setText(pricehour);
                }
                public void setPricehday(String pricehday)
                {
                    TextView PostPricehday = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_prichalfday);
                    PostPricehday.setText(pricehday);
                }
                public void setPriceday(String priceday)
                {
                    TextView PostPriceday = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_priceday);
                    PostPriceday.setText(priceday);
                }

                public void setPostimage(Context ctx1, String postimage)
                {
                    ImageView PostImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_post_image);
                    Picasso.with(ctx1).load(postimage).into(PostImage);
                }
                public void setState( String state)
                {
                    Button State = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.book_button);
                    State.setText(state);
                    if (state.equals("Booked")){

                    }
                    System.out.println("Stat"+state);
                  ;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();

                FirebaseUser currentUser =  CustomerAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(currentUser == null)
                {
                    SendUserToCustomerloginActivity();
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckUserExistence();
                }
            }
            // to see if the user validation and his authenticated so if not, the user will be send to the setup activity.

            private void CheckUserExistence()
            {
                final String current_user_id = CustomerAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                CustomerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public      void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                        {
                            SendUserToCustomerSetupActivity();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            private void SendUserToCustomerSetupActivity()
            {
                Intent setupIntent = new Intent(CustomerDrawer.this, CustomerSetup.class);
                setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(setupIntent);
                finish();
            }




            private void SendUserToCustomerloginActivity() {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(CustomerDrawer.this,CustomerLogin.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
                finish();
            }


            private void SendUserToCustomerProfile() {
                Intent ProfileIntent = new Intent(CustomerDrawer.this,CustomerProfile.class);
                ProfileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(ProfileIntent);
                finish();
            }

            private void SendUserToWelcomeActivity() {
                Intent WelcomeIntent = new Intent(CustomerDrawer.this,Grober_Welcome.class);
                WelcomeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(WelcomeIntent);
                finish();
            }

            private void SendUserToSettingsActivity()
            {
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(CustomerDrawer.this, CustomerSettings.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent );

            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.Customer_drawer_layout);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_Profile) {
                    SendUserToCustomerProfile();

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_Edit_profile) {
                    SendUserToSettingsActivity();
                }

                else if (id == R.id.nav_Logout) {
                    CustomerAuth.signOut();
                    SendUserToWelcomeActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(CustomerDrawer.this, "Logged Out Successfull...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.Customer_drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            }


        }
```

Comment: I can not understand your problem

Comment: I have chat activity and i need when any user of these two click on the contact button to be directed to the chat activity and see the another user id and username but when i pass the id by intent, the setup activity takes this id and check in the firebase for his other details and it sees that the id don't have any other details. so it direc him to the setup activity again like he is new. but actually the id is the anothe user id

Comment: Maybe you can post a diagram of that flow... You are putting names to your activities but we don't know where are we standing and which should be the correct flow. For example, your are also saying: *I have chat activity and i need when any user of these two click on the contact button to be directed to the chat activity*.. if you are at the chat activity how is it that you want to be directed to the chat activity? Where does the setup activity come in?

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify, if you leave it as a comment it won't be as visible.

Comment: have two users activities owner and customer. owner post cars for rent and post will be posted in both activities. in post there is contact button.  contact button direct owner to chat activity and he supposes to see customer username and profile image but it only shows the personal image and username. therefore i'm trying to get the user id of the owner to use it in the cutomer activity and the opposite. but , unfortunatly when i do that, the setup activity take  user id which i have took and check in  user name that user have not entered his details and direct him again to setup activity